# Devise Google Omniauth working in Local, but not in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, production

Google OAuth2 on Production is not working for me. This is with the Devise gem.

The log shows this all the time on Production. (Removed Prefixed output from server)

```
Started POST "/users/auth/google_oauth2" for 112.205.146.56 at 2023-01-27 01:14:38 +0000
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit.x"=>"25", "commit.y"=>"16"}
Redirected to https://automateton.com/users/sign_in
```

But it works on Local!!!

```
Started POST "/users/auth/google_oauth2" for ::1 at 2023-01-27 09:20:01 +0800
DEBUG -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
```

The `.rbenv-vars` should work in Production as I've put the secret and master key there. I've also put my DB creds and Google creds there.

Gemfile includes

```
gem 'devise
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-rails_csrf_protection'
```

Localhost omniauth includes

```
localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback # Redirect URI in Google Developer Console
```

Can you help me with this? Thank you very much!

I've also tried the following:

1. Added SSL certification with Let's Encrypt
2. Added callback to my `www.example.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback` (redacted domain name)
3. Changed Google Oauth from test mode to production mode.

EDIT: I tried switching to Sorcery Gem and realized that the problem still persists. I think it's the CSRF problem that was already present in the other questions. However, I've tried the solutions already and they don't work.

e.g. if I use the `skip_verify_token` (non-verbatim) action or the `protect_from_forgery prepend: true`. It still doesn't work as the user is still not logged in (for both Sorcery and Devise). I still get sent back to the sign in page.

So, I went back to Devise to get a higher possibility stack overflow answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a facepalm moment for me. I've apparently set my `config/initializers/session_store.rb` to `sample.com` for the domain. So both OmniAuth for google and actual `users/sign_in` isn't working.

My settings before

```
domain = Rails.env.development? ? 'localhost' : 'sample.com'
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session', domain:
```

```
domain = Rails.env.development? ? 'localhost' : 'appname.com' # appname redacted but I changed it to the actual host name
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session', domain: (ruby 3.1.0, domain: domain shortcut)
```

Now it works!